# Fixed width and height for new opened folder/file

Tags: 11.10, unity

I don't like to open file and then adjust height and width, which always quite the same for every file and folder. Do you know if I could make fixed height and width for new opened folder or file? Of course then I could resize it if I wanted to. Thank you very much.

Comment: OP are you still looking for an answer? If so, you may need to repost your question as this is flagged for closure. Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install Compiz Config Settings Manager

[image]

Compiz desktop effects are available in your Ubuntu by default and if you have any kind of 3D acceleration available(graphics driver ie), you are good to go with Compiz.

Now to tweak Compiz desktop effects in Ubuntu, you need to install "compizconfig-settings-manager" package. Simply copy paste the following command into Terminal to install "compizconfig-settings-manager".

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

If you want to enable some extra animation plug-ins like Burn, Airplane, Paint fire on the screen, etc., you'll need to install the 'compiz-fusion-plugins-extra' package also.

```
sudo apt-get install compiz-fusion-plugins-extra
```

**This is where you will get the options under "Window Management"**

Place - Put - Resize - Scale - Move and many others